# select group of rows that matches all its associated items to a list

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, having-clause

I got a table:

```
id|name
------
1|Tom
1|Lucy
1|Frank
2|Lucy
2|Frank
3|Frank
4|Jane
5|Robert
6|John
```

Need result of id's where all the names associated with a specific id match to the list

The list is ('Lucy','Frank','Jane','Robert','Brandon').

I've tried this:

```
select id 
from table 
group by id 
having name in('Lucy','Frank','Jane','Robert','Brandon')
```

Obtained result:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Desired Result:

```
2
3
4
5
```

What's excluded: the count(distinct id) > 2000
the list contains 200 names and each id is associated with at least 1 name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use aggregation, and a `having` clause that ensures that none of the `name`s in the group does not belong to the list:

```
select id
from mytable
group by id
having max(name not in ('Lucy', 'Frank', 'Jane', 'Robert', 'Brandon')) = 0
```